# Criteria expression representing timestamp before 5 minutes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

How to create a Expression representing timestamp before 5 minutes of the current timestamp using the JPA 2.0 criteria API?

There is one table with run_date column. I need to select all the records where run_date is in last 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("someTimestamp", cal.getTime()));
```

This is the easiest way to do it. The other option is to create your own Criterion implementation, but unless you need it a whole lot of times, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply JB. But I am afraid that the Calendar object will have data/timestamp of the machine on which I will be executing java code. Which will be different than the one on DB machine.